# jQuery - Calculate minWidth

Tags: jquery, variables, css

> [View jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkBRE/1/)

Attempting to set the `min-Width` of a `<menu>` by calculating the total width of all the `<command>` elements inside of the `<menu>`. I tried my best to figure it out in the following `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('menu').each(function() {

        var minWidth;

        $('menu command').each(function() {
            minWidth = minWidth + $(this).outerWidth(); 
        });

        $(this).css('min-width', minWidth);
    });
});
```

This is the format for the `HTML`:

```
<menu>
    <command class="less" />
    <command class="more" />

    <div class="space"></div>

    <command class="save" />
    <command class="vote" />
    <command class="send" />
</menu>
```

> The `div.space` is just a seperator that I'm going to code later to split the commands across the full length.

My code currently comes up with no errors.

> [View jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkBRE/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining the minWidth variable you forgot to set it to 0. You also forgot to add 'px' behind the number when setting the CSS. Here's your code, working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('menu').each(function() {

        var minWidth = 0;

        $('menu command').each(function() {
            minWidth = minWidth + $(this).outerWidth();
        });

        $(this).css('min-width', minWidth + 'px');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kkBRE/5/

Comment: that did make the code work only its not calculating perfectly if you resize the results pane you'll see why.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to take into account the margins and paddings of the commands

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('menu').each(function() {

        var minWidth = 0;

        $('menu command').each(function() {
            minWidth = minWidth + ($(this).width());
        });
        minWidth = minWidth+35;

        $(this).css('min-width', minWidth + 'px');
    });
});
```